# Options of the function scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I am trying to minimize a very long function (it is the sum of 500000 parts of sub-functions) in order to fit some parameters to a probabilistic model. I use the `scipy.optimize.minimize` function. I tried both `Powell` and `Nelder-Mead` algorithms, and Powell looks really faster in my settings. But still, I really don't understand how to force the process to give me some results after a given time, even if they are not "optimal".

I fill the options `maxiter`, `maxfev`, `xtol` and `ftol`, but I don't really understand these options, since I tried to put a `print` in my function and I noticed that the algorithm evaluate it more than `maxfev` times, but when It reaches the maxiter point, It sends an error "max number of iterations reached".

How do they work with respect to the two algorithms I am using? The doc is very unclear.

My code:

```
def log_likelihood(r, alpha, a, b, customers):
    if r <= 0 or alpha <= 0 or a <= 0 or b <= 0:
        return -np.inf
    c = sum([log_likelihood_individual(r, alpha, a, b, x, tx, t) for x, tx, t in customers])
    print -c
    return c

negative_ll = lambda params: -log_likelihood(*params,customers=customers)
params0 = (1, 1, 1, 1)
res = minimize(negative_ll, params0, method='Powell', callback=print_callback, options={'disp': True, 'ftol':0.05, 'maxiter':3, 'maxfev":15})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably ask this on the scipy mailing list, or even the scipy developer mailing list, but looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L386) for the Nelder-Mead algorithm, I notice the actual check on `maxiter` and `maxfev` are in the outer while loop. The function is called several times inside that while loop, so the actual number of function evaluations can easily surpass `maxfev`. 
Something similar happens inside the [main loop](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L2289) for Powell's method. For that method, it appears the function is evaluated `N` times before the number of evaluations is tested (`N` the number of parameters).

I guess this is done because otherwise there would be too many `if` statements inside the core loops that check against `maxfev`, and it was deemed faster/clearer to have the condition outside the inner loops.